# Item is appearing with delay

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I have problem with images list and popup image. Item is appearing with delay when I added element. I have custom popUp displayed while adding a photo. When done, it disappears. And I would like it to disappear after being displayed. The same behavior occurs when displaying popUp with the selected photo. PopUp appears but the photo appears after quite a long delay. I paste fragment of my code

```cs
 await Task.Run(async () =>
{
     try
    {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                    {
                        await popUp.ShowPopUp();
                    });
    
                    //fragment of add photo to ObservableCollection

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
                     Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        popUp.ClosePopup();
                    });   
    }




});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please elaborate with code of adding image and calling your task etc.

Comment: @DominikLorke How do you display images list, and how do you add element? What is your custom popUp? please share mode detailed code.

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT code added

Answer (score 0):

List of Images

```
 <syncfusion:SfListView 
                Grid.Row="0"                
                ItemSpacing="3"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PhotoItems}"
                ItemSize="100"
                ItemTapped="ItemTapped">                
                <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ffimageloading:CachedImage
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            </syncfusion:SfListView>
```

add element

```
Image im = new Image(my image with cystom properties);
PhotoItems.Add(im);
```